# Как заменить значение в строке, FREERADIUS + APC Outlets

Tags: python, freeradius

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь автоматизировать работу `freeradius` для замены значений в конфиге.

Вводные данные:

1. Словарь для оборудования `APC` в `radius/dictionary`
2. Блок значений для пользователя в виде,

   ```
   ipetrov
               Auth-Type = ntlm_auth,
               APC-Service-Type = Outlet,
               APC-Outlets = "1[1,3,5];"
   ```

   где необходимо менять значения внутри квадратных скобок, всего значений от 1 до 24, одновременное количество значений неизвестно (т.е. пользователь может работать как с одним значением, например `APC-Outlets = "1[24];"`, так и с несколькими, например `APC-Outlets = "1[11,18,22];"`
3. Пользователей, естественно, под сотню. А значит и таких блоков в файле `radius/users.conf` будет под сотню. Не обязательно, что все сто пользователей будут работать одновременно, но иметь блоки пользователей необходимо заранее (а может, и нет?)

Задача:

1. Иметь возможность динамически менять значения в `APC-Outlets = "1[11,18,22];"` для нужного пользователя.

Как это вижу я:

1. Пользователь запускает программу, программа принимает значение `username` через команду `whoami`, пользователь указывает нужные ему значения через запятую
   `./script.sh 1,2,3`
   ИЛИ программа предлагает ввести нужны значения через `input`
2. Далее выбирается рабочая директория freeradius
   `workdir=/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files/`
3. Программа находит блок пользователя `username` в файле users.conf
4. Программа меняет значение внутри скобок `APC-Outlets = "1[];"` на введенные значения из `input`

Все бы хорошо, но мой стаж программирования на Python позволяет сделать только следующее:

1. Пробую создать блок целиком, меняя значение переменной:

```
username = input('Имя пользователя: ')
apc_outlets = str(input('Номера розеток: '))
file_path = ('test.conf')


block = (username + '\n'
                  '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + "Auth-Type = ntlm_auth," + '\n'
                  '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + "APC-Service-Type = Outlet," + '\n'
                  '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + 'APC-Outlets = "1[' + apc_outlets + '];"' + '\n' + '\n')

with open(file_path, 'a+') as file:
  file.write(block)
```

Окей, как создавать блоки я понял, пробую менять значение внутри блока у переменной `apc_outlets`:

```
with open(file_path, 'a+') as file:
    apc_outlets_new = apc_outlets
    apc_replaced = block.replace(apc_outlets, apc_outlets_new)
    file.write(apc_replaced)
```

И тут я понял, что метод `replace` не меняет значение внутри строки, а записывает новую строку с новым значением, т.е. сейчас я имею два блока с одним юзернеймом, но с разными значениями `APC-Outlets = "1[];"`. Увы, это не то, что я хотел.

Ладно, попробуем посчитать строки, будем отталкиваться от них

```
username = input('Имя пользователя: ')
apc_outlets = str(input('Номера розеток: '))
apc = 'APC-Outlets = '
file_path = ('test.conf')

with open(file_path, 'a+') as file:
    n = 0
    for line in file:
        n += 1
        if username in line:
            print(username, 'найден в строке', n)
            n = 0
            for line_two in file:
                n += 1
                if apc in line_two:
                    print(apc, 'найден в строке', n)
                    break
```

Отлично! Я могу найти номер строки переменной `username`, а потом найти номер нужной мне строки с параметрами  `APC-Outlets = "1[];"`

И все. Дальше не могу сдвинуться с места уже неделю. Я не могу понять, как можно осуществить замену значений без удаления всего содержимого файла (например, через `with open(file_path, 'r+') as file:`) или без создания нового содержимого через метод `replace`.

Есть ли какой-то вариант решения моей задачи? Как можно менять значение в подстроке, не меняя больше ничего?

Мне очень жаль, что пришлось написать такую простыню, но я не представляю, как можно описать задачу по иному.

Возможно, вы подскажете новый вариант решения этой задачи.

Comment: Вот реализовал мой вариант решения [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222885/267338) для вашей задачи, написал функцию модификации конфиг файла используя регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот реализовал центральную функцию `modify_config()` которая делает нужные действия. Её вызывает некая `main()` в которой читается файл плюс имя пользователя и аутлеты, модифицируется конфиг через `modify_config()` и записывается результирующий конфиг.

Поиск и чтение/запись именно нужного конфиг файла не делал, т.к. посчитал что основная трудность это именно внесение изменений в конфиг.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222861#main.py)

```
import re

def modify_config(text, user, outlets):
    cuser, res, ufound, fixed = None, '', False, False
    for iline, line in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
        if line.strip():
            m = re.fullmatch(r'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+?)\s*$', line)
            if m:
                cuser = m.group(1)
                if cuser == user:
                    ufound = True
            else:
                m = re.fullmatch(r'^\s+(.+?)\s*\=\s*(.+?)\s*$', line)
                assert m, f'Unmatched line "{line}" at line {iline}!'
                l, r = m.group(1), m.group(2)
                if cuser == user and l == 'APC-Outlets':
                    m2 = re.fullmatch(r'^\".*\[(.*)\].*\"$', r)
                    assert m2, f'Unmatched outlets "{r}" at line {iline}!'
                    line = line[:m.span(2)[0] + m2.span(1)[0]] + outlets + line[m.span(2)[0] + m2.span(1)[1]:]
                    m3 = re.fullmatch(r'^\s+APC-Outlets\s*\=\s*\".*\[' + outlets + r'\]\.*\"\s*$', line)
                    assert m3, f'Unmatched resulting outlets "{line}" at line {iline}!'
                    fixed = True
        res += line + '\n'
    assert ufound, f'User "{user}" not found in config!'
    assert fixed, f'No modifications made!'
    return res

def main():
    user = input('Username: ').strip()
    outlets = ','.join([str(int(e)) for e in re.split(r'[\s,;]+', input('Outlets: ').strip()) if e.strip()])
    with open('0296.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
        text = f.read()
    rtext = modify_config(text, user, outlets)
    with open('0296.txt2', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(rtext)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Пример входного файла:

```
ipetrov
            Auth-Type = ntlm_auth,
            APC-Service-Type = Outlet,
            APC-Outlets = "1[1,3,5];"
isidorov
            Auth-Type = ntlm_auth,
            APC-Service-Type = Outlet,
            APC-Outlets = "1[];"
```

Пример ввода консоли:

```
Username: ipetrov
Outlets: 1,2,3
```

Пример результирующего файла:

```
ipetrov
            Auth-Type = ntlm_auth,
            APC-Service-Type = Outlet,
            APC-Outlets = "1[1,2,3];"
isidorov
            Auth-Type = ntlm_auth,
            APC-Service-Type = Outlet,
            APC-Outlets = "1[];"
```

Answer (score 0):

Для потомков.
Данный скрипт полностью игнорирует формат ввода и преобразует его в читабельный для конфига радиуса вид. Плюс прикрутил сюда простой логгер.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re
import logging
import os
import getpass


logging.basicConfig(
                    level=logging.DEBUG, filename='/var/log/auth_script.log',
                    format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s => %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
                    )
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


USERNAME = getpass.getuser()
os.chdir('/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files')
pwd = os.getcwd()
INPUT_FILE = 'authorize'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'authorize'


# text_color просто разукрашивает текст.
class TextColor:
    Red = '\033[91m'
    Green = '\033[92m'
    END = '\033[0m'


# input_data() принимает и проверяет правильность входящих данных
def input_data():
    try:
        welcome = 'Пожалуйста, введите значения от 1 до 24 через запятую или одно число.\n' \
                  + 'Пример: 1,2,3 или 24 или 4 5 6 или любой другой символ в качестве разделителя.'
        print(welcome)
        outlets_input = input()
        logging.debug('Получение данных... Вывод: %s', outlets_input)
        splitting_outlets = re.split(r"\D+", outlets_input)
        logging.debug('Преобразование строки в список... Вывод: %s', splitting_outlets)
        space = ''
        while space in splitting_outlets:
            splitting_outlets.remove('')
            logging.debug('Удаление пустых объектов... Вывод: %s', splitting_outlets)
            if len(splitting_outlets) == 0:
                bad_input = '   Вы ничего не ввели! Пожалуйста, запустите программу заново.'
                logging.error('Пустой ввод!')
                logging.info('Прерывание работы скрипта.')
                raise SystemExit(TextColor.Red + str(splitting_outlets) + bad_input + TextColor.END)
        transform_outlets = list(set(map(int, splitting_outlets)))
        logging.debug('Преобразование списка в числа... Вывод: %s', transform_outlets)
        transform_outlets.sort()
        logging.debug('Сортировка списка... Вывод: %s', transform_outlets)
        if 1 <= min(transform_outlets) and max(transform_outlets) <= 24:
            outlets = ','.join(str(e) for e in transform_outlets)
            logging.debug('Преобразование данных для записи... Вывод: %s', outlets)
            return outlets
        else:
            bad_data = '   Введённые данные отличаются от требуемых. ' \
                       'Пожалуйста, запустите программу заново и введите число от 1 до 24.'
            logging.error('Введённые данные отличаются от требуемых! ')
            logging.info('Прерывание работы скрипта.')
            raise SystemExit(TextColor.Red + str(transform_outlets) + bad_data + TextColor.END)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(e)


# check_username() проверка пользователя
def check_username():
    try:
        with open(INPUT_FILE, "r") as data:
            username = USERNAME
            logger.debug('Чтение пользователя ' + username + '...')
            text = data.read()
            logging.debug('Поиск пользователя в файле...')
            if username in text:
                logging.debug('Пользователь ' + username + ' найден!')
                return True
            else:
                logging.error('Пользователя с таким именем не существует!')
                logging.info('Прерывание работы скрипта.')
                raise SystemExit(TextColor.Red + 'Пользователя с таким именем не существует!\n'
                                                 'Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с системным администратором.' + TextColor.END)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(e)


# modification_data() заменяет текст согласно шаблону
def modification_data(outlets):
    try:
        with open(INPUT_FILE, 'r') as data:
            search_string = 'APC-Outlets'
            text = data.read()
            matched_user = None
            modified_text = ''
            for line_number, line_data in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
                match = re.fullmatch(r'^([\w\d.]+)\s*$', line_data)
                if match:
                    matched_user = match.group(1)
                else:
                    match = re.fullmatch(r'^\s+' + search_string + r'.*\"\s*$', line_data)
                    if match and matched_user == USERNAME:
                        logging.debug('Строка для изменения значений на строке номер %s', line_number)
                        logging.debug('Старые данные %s', line_data)
                        line_data = "\t\t\tAPC-Outlets = \"1[" + outlets + "];\""
                        logging.debug('Новые данные %s', line_data)
                modified_text += line_data + '\n'
                with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as mod_data:
                    mod_data.write(modified_text)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(e)


def ready_to_go(outlets):
    try:
        s = ','
        if s not in outlets:
            logging.info('Розетка номер ' + outlets + ' готова к работе!')
            print(TextColor.Green + 'Розетка номер ' + outlets + ' готова к работе!' + TextColor.END)
        elif outlets:
            logging.info('Розетки номер ' + outlets + ' готовы к работе!')
            print(TextColor.Green + 'Розетки номер ' + outlets + ' готовы к работе!' + TextColor.END)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(e)


def main():
    check_username()
    outlets = input_data()
    modification_data(outlets)
    ready_to_go(outlets)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```